# Get UML diagram from relational database

Tags: postgresql, uml

I use PostegresQL 9. Is there a free tool to derive UML diagrams from my databases?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For creating ER diagrams by db reflection, I use:
DbVisualizer

http://www.dbvis.com/

It's free.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. DbVisualizer connects to a database and outputs the relationships along with lots of other useful information. Very straightforward, available for Mac/Linux/Windows.

Comment: Yep, yet is a rare case when I have to admit that a java app is quite good :)

Comment: i just found it is included in arch linux's aur database.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [postgresql_autodoc](https://github.com/cbbrowne/autodoc) which can create [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) or [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) output.  The diagrams will likely require further tweaking, though.

Comment: That link is now broken

Answer (score 3):

Found DBeaver here:

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34552/generate-database-table-diagrams-from-a-postgresql-database

Tested it with postgres. Works great.

https://dbeaver.io/download/

free, multi-platform universal SQL client. Supports all popular databases: MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, SQLite, Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase, MS Access, Teradata, Firebird, Derby, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's a free tool called [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/) and a plugin called [PostDia](https://github.com/chebizarro/postdia). They would do it for you.

Plus:

1. it generates postegres sql scheme files too
2. Both are **free**.

Requirements for PostDia: python and psycopg2, to install the second one:

`pip install psycopg2`

Answer (score 0):

I think [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) can do it. Let us know

EDIT: Actually ArgoUML does not seem to reverse engineer, take a look at http://databasetouml.org/roadmap.php or search more for extensions to Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

EclipseUML can do the job but it is not free. What is cool with this tool is that they have a database profile therefore you can see full database information into your class diagram.

Answer (score 0):

There was [Azzurri Clay](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-ecldbint/section4.html) plugin for Eclipse with db reverse engineering support (v 1.4 as I remember). But in v 2.0 the [company developing this plugin](http://www.azzurri.jp/) moved the reverse engineering feature to the licensed version of the plugin. There were some manuals in the internet how to downgrade from v2 to v1.